# How can I quickly test SOCKS proxy with python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy

I have created working Python script to retrieve supposedly working SOCKS4/SOCKS5 "Elite" proxies, but it seems they are not working at all for me, at least according to my second Python script ;-)

Is following a proper way to test if I successfuly apply proxy on my request?

```py
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

proxies_list = []

with open('../proxies.txt', 'r') as proxies_file:
    proxies_list = [line.rstrip() for line in proxies_file]

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, "
                         "like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"}
counter = 0
# just testing first few
for index in range(len(proxies_list) - 90):
    proxies = {
        "http://": proxies_list[index],
        "https://": proxies_list[index],
    }

    try:
        # print("Attempting try with", proxies_list[index])
        page = requests.get(url='https://ipaddress.my/', proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        detected_ip = soup.find("ul", {"class": "list-inline text-center"}).find("li", recursive=False).find("span", recursive=False).text

        # ip in ip:port format   
        if detected_ip in proxies_list[index]:
            counter += 1

        # print(f"Tested {proxies_list[index]} and detected {detected_ip}")
        time.sleep(2)
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError as error:
        pass

print(f'In total, made {counter} connections.')
```

Unfortunately, outcome looks like this:

[image]

Is there better way to implement requests via proxy, or my proxies are just not working?

Answer (score 0):

You specified http and https proxies, change the url scheme to `socks5://` and `socks4://`